# Visual SVN and Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 won't play nice

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visual-studio-2010

I can't seem to get Visual SVN and Visual Studio Beta 2 to work together, anyone know of a workaround???

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is known problem. We're working on it and provide fix soon.

As workaround you may copy file "C:\Program Files\[Prev Visual studio]\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\microsoft.visualstudio.dll" to C:\Program Files\VisualSVN\bin directory.

Comment: If you have x64, it might be in your Program Files (x86).

Comment: [Prev Visual Studio] = Your previous version of visual studio.  For some reason I wasn't sure what "Prev" stood for and looked through my 2010 folder for this.  Just a note for anyone who might make the same dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The latest generation VisualSVN in reporting Visual Studio 2010 compatibility: http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/

There's also a post about getting it to work with the first beta here: http://mikeownage.com/wordpress/?p=336

Answer (score 1):

The workaround solved the problem for me. Look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies for the dll.

Answer (score 0):

I know [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is working on it. Might you give them a try?

Have you updated to a recent build?

[VisualSVN change log](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/)

Answer (score 0):

Ivan: The workaround to copy a DLL describes a DLL that I am unable to locate. I don't have a "microsoft.visualstudio.dll".
Can you please elaborate?

EDIT:
Ahhh ... I think my browser had left out the ..\[Prev Visual studio]\.. part. I just read an empty segment ..\\.., and so I was looking for it in the Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 folder. Found it!
Thanks.

Comment: Please post this as a comment.