# Visual Studio 2010 - Opened ASPX files are uneditable

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I came across an Issue in Visual studio 2010. Sometimes when I open .ASPX files they are uneditable. Files are not read-only. Usually it is possible to edit them but time to time it just disable editing. I have to restart whole VS and then when I open the very same file I am able to edit it.

Does anyone have/had similar experience? Is there some kind of fix for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not-editable"? Are you able to type changes? What does the cursor look like? Does saving work? Do you receive an error message? Which version of Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @mason by "not-editable" I mean that I am not able to do any changes. I cant create/delete/edit code. I am not getting any errors, cursor looks normal (usual flashing | ) VS version: Professional

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editing aspx/ascx files randomly disabled in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450617/editing-aspx-ascx-files-randomly-disabled-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VS patch seems to fix the issue:

- http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=40811

link mentioned in following Question:

- [Editing aspx/ascx files randomly disabled in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450617/editing-aspx-ascx-files-randomly-disabled-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

this is the bug in Visual Studio. This is not just for you. I too faced the issue. Try upgrading to latest version.

Also this link may be helpful

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615270/file-becomes-completely-uneditable-read-only-in-certain-circumstances

Comment: Interesting link but Microsoft's resolution: "Unfortunately, addressing this issue doesn't meet the bar for the next version of the product." Is not not helping at all.

Comment: Do you get some clarification?

Comment: check this post, there seems to be some work arounds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450617/editing-aspx-ascx-files-randomly-disabled-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: @Paritosh this seems to work. Posting as answer. Thanks